# What causes Hibernate Session#update to be slow?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following:

```
public void batchSave(Iterable<T> entities) {
    int i = 0;

    for (T entity : entities) {
        session.update(entity);
        i++;

        if (i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
    }

    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}
```

This method is invoked on 2 occasions, once with an input of size ~28000 and once with an input of size ~32000, so not much difference in terms of size.

However, the latter takes much much longer to run. My question is what would cause this function to run longer once as opposed to the other time? Given all other properties are equal between the two, I would expect these to finish in similar time.

My understanding is that `session.update(object)` issues an update to the DB, but I should note that in the group of 32000, almost all of the objects have had their state modified, whereas for the 28000 only about 5000 of them have. Even so, the 28000 size collection takes maybe 2s while the slightly larger one seems to run for minutes.

Comment: What is the value of BATCH_SIZE? Are all this entities instances of the same class? Are you changing properties of the entities or are you making modifications to other entities related to the ones in the list?

Comment: This may be useful https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/

Comment: `BATCH_SIZE = 50` and the necessary hibernate properties are set. Object models are different, but not complicated, simple POJOs with Strings, Integers and Doubles and in fact the one with the smaller collection size is a large POJO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an oversight in that the latter table was not correctly indexed, so the updates were taking longer at the DB.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of [auto (deferred) flushing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateAccessor.html#FLUSH_AUTO). Split them into two differrent transactions and the speed might be more comparable.

Comment: I am using Spring Data Repositories pattern here, so this is wrapped in a method that is decorated with `@Transactional` . Is this incorrect?